# The group divider always turn black

Tags: android, layout, expandablelistview

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandable_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_weight="5"        
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"             
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"   
        android:divider="#212121"   
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"  
        android:background="#ffffff" />
```

I want to make the divider of group and child grey, the child divider is ok but the group divider always turn black. Please show me how to fix this

IMAGE:[image]
http://s27.postimg.org/r6h213p9f/Untitled.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandable_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_weight="5"        
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"             
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"   
        android:divider="#C0C0C0"   
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"  
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

Comment: Ur welcome.android:divider="#212121" ? . it will remain black due to #212121 is black.try to analyse the code for happy coding :)